# function works when htmlDocument created inside function but not when htmlDocument created outside and passed as argument

Tags: vb.net

Firstly here is my code:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
Public Property myPage As HtmlDocument

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    myPage = OpenDoc(txtURL.Text)
    'Dim myPage As HtmlDocument = OpenDoc(txtURL.Text)
    Dim tmp = NameGroup(myPage)
    Dim tmp1 = NextPage(myPage) 'txtURL.Text)
    'Dim tmp2 = ProvinceLinks(myPage)
    'Dim tmp3 = CityLinks(myPage)
End Sub

Public Function OpenDoc(ByVal url As String) As HtmlDocument
    If (url Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("url")

    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

    Return document
End Function

Public Function NameGroup(ByVal document As HtmlDocument) As List(Of String)
    Dim myNameGroup As New List(Of String)

    If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then
        Dim rootNode As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
        If (Not rootNode Is Nothing) Then
            document.LoadHtml(rootNode.InnerHtml())
            If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then

                Dim node As HtmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr//td//p//a")

                For Each n In node
                    'Dim myProvince = n.InnerText
                    Dim myUrl = n.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myUrl) Then myNameGroup.Add("https://411.ca" & myUrl)
                Next

                Return myNameGroup
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Function NextPage(document As HtmlDocument) As String  'url As String) As String '
    Dim myNextPage As String = Nothing

    'If (url Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("url")

    'Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    'Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

    If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then
        Dim rootNode As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")
        If (Not rootNode Is Nothing) Then
            document.LoadHtml(rootNode.InnerHtml())
            If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then
                Dim node As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='pagination']")
                myNextPage = node.ChildNodes("a").GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)

                Return myNextPage
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The Function OpenDoc works by providing an HTMLDocument object. This object is then used as an argument for other functions. This way the internet has to be accessed only once per URL.

This works fine for all but one function. My NextPage function will not work with this Function provided document object.

If you take a look at the NextPage function above you will see the same code, as in the OpenDoc function, commented out. When I uncomment this code and pass the URL the function works. When I comment the code and pass the myPage object argument to NextPage as either a property or as a local variable (you can see my comment mark next to the local variable), the NextPage function does not work.

The NextPage function passes it's "If (Not document.DocumentNode Is Nothing) Then" test but fails on the "If (Not rootNode Is Nothing) Then" test when I use the function provided HTMLDocument object.

The btnStart Sub is my Function Test sub. The commented out code is code that works. tmp and tmp1 share the same argument. tmp works and tmp1 does not.

I've tried to be as concise and provide as much information as possible without being redundant.
One would expect if it works for one it would work for all and visa versa. I'm not seeing the problem. Any ideas? If you need full code and URL let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the code for NameGroup? Maybe there is something in there that's causing problems for NextPage?

Comment: Oops. After all that I included the wrong function. I've corrected the above code with the correct function.

Comment: Ok. Here is what I've figured out so far. My NameGroup function is modifying the HTMLDocument. When I commented NameGroup function out I get the complete HTMLDocument. I think I remember something about changes made to the variable assignment affect the original variable as well. I'll need to look into that farther. If this is true then I need to figure out how I can make a truly independent variable copy.

Answer (score 0):

My NameGroup function was modifying the HTMLDocument.

When NameGroup runs the code

```
Dim rootNode As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
Document.LoadHtml(rootNode.InnerHtml())
```

it changes the original Document value.

What I needed to do was to assign the RootNode to a new htmldocument variable.
eg.

```
Dim myDocument As New HtmlDocument
Dim rootNode As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
myDocument.LoadHtml(rootNode.InnerHtml())
```

This leaves Document unchanged.